# Change Background color of Menu Button in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I tried changing background color of menu button in plotly, code is running sucessfully but "bgcolor:grey" changes are not applied.

I checked documentation and used same syntax,code is running.

Code-

```
df['vix'] = nf_vix['Close'].round(decimals = 1)

fig = go.Figure(
      data=[ go.Scatter(x=df.index,y=df.vix, line=dict(color='green', width=3),name='Low Volatility',fill='tozeroy'),
             go.Scatter(x=df.index,y=df.vix.where(df.vix >= 20), mode='lines+markers',line=dict(color='red', width=3),name='High Volatality',fill='toself')],
             layout_title_text="NIFTY Volatality Index" )

#Hide Weekends and Added Range Slider
fig.update_xaxes( rangeslider_visible=True, rangebreaks=[ dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"])])
fig.update_layout( xaxis_tickformat = ' %d %B (%a)<br> %Y',xaxis_title='Date',yaxis_title='Range',template ='plotly_dark',legend = dict(bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'))
##https://plotly.com/python/legend/
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=1.02,
    xanchor="right",
    x=1
))
# fig.add_hrect(y0=0, y1=20, 
#               annotation_text="Low volatality", annotation_position="top left",
#               fillcolor="green", opacity=0.25, line_width=0)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(rangeselector=dict(buttons=list([
               dict(count=1,label="1m",step="month",stepmode="backward"),dict(count=3,label="3m",step="month",stepmode="backward"),
               dict(count=6,label="6m",step="month",stepmode="backward"),
               dict(count=1,label="YTD",step="year",stepmode="todate"),
               dict(step="all") ])  ),rangeslider=dict(visible=False),type="date"))
# fig.update_layout(updatemenus=dict(bgcolor = 'grey'))
fig.update_layout({
'updatemenus': [{'bgcolor' : 'grey'}]})

fig.show()
```

doc- https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/

Viz Snap -

[image: VIZ]

Update--
Now I have added the below code in above code, the font color changed to "black". I want to know if "background color" of "range selector" buttons can be changed or not.

I got github link but this attribute `rangeselector.activebgcolor` is not working.
Link - https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/790

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(rangeselector = dict(font = dict( color = "black"))))
```

Updated Snap-

[image: Updated VIZ with Black Font color]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: The font color and background color of the range selector button and the background color of the active button can be changed with The answer is taken from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#time-series-with-range-selector-buttons).

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y='AAPL.High', title='Time Series with Range Slider and Selectors')

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeslider_visible=True,
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
            dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(step="all")
        ])
    )
)
# update
fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_font_color='black',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_activecolor='red',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_bgcolor='green',
                 )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners, I changed font color. Viz looks better than previous. Can we change background color also?

I updated my question.

Comment: Updated with button background, button font color, and active button background color.